# CS50 Mario - Help on Error; Data argument not used by format string

Tags: c, cs50, format-string

I can't finish the mario and don't know why it is not working.

I watched a video and someone used "void print (char c, int n); as a protocode(?)on top but I don't get why it should be there.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("Height: ");
    }
    while (n < 1 || n > 8); 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf(".", n - 1 - I);
        printf("#", i + 1);
        printf("\n");
    }     
}
```

Error:

```
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    marioblock.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o marioblock
marioblock.c:14:19: error: data argument not used by format string
      [-Werror,-Wformat-extra-args]
      printf(".", n - 1 - i);
             ~~~  ^
marioblock.c:15:19: error: data argument not used by format string
      [-Werror,-Wformat-extra-args]
      printf("#", i + 1);
             ~~~  ^
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a syntax error. You use `printf` in a wrong way (the arguments). You may want to use `for loop` to print the same symbol for many times.

For instance, the following code will print 3 hashes `###` ;

```
int main(void)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

To achieve mario pset, use one for loop to print hashes, use another for loop to print spaces. I hope this helps you to understand the design.